# Why gain crossover frequency must be lower than phase crossover frequency for stable systems?

Tags: control, control-system, control-theory, loop-gain, phase-margin

As far as I understood from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ThoA4amCAX4), phase margin means the amount of phase that needs to be added in order to coincide with 0 db gain and -180 degrees phase. Likewise for the gain margin it means means the amount of gain that needs to be added in order to coincide with 0 db gain and -180 degrees phase. But i don't understand why do they both necessarily have to be positive for stable systems?

Re-stating my question. I want to know: **Why gain crossover frequency must be lower than phase crossover frequency for stable systems**?

[image]

Relevant: [Can a phase margin become bigger than 180° and is this bad?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442225/can-a-phase-margin-become-bigger-than-180-and-is-this-bad?rq=1)

Comment: Positive gain and phase margin for stable systems is just convention.

Comment: You might also look up "stability margin" which is the shortest distance from the Nyquist curve to the critical point. It captures the other two ideas.

Comment: Look up Barkhausen's criterion.   The old joke, is "my amplifiers oscillate, and my oscillators don't".

Comment: Read about Harry Nyquist.

Comment: @Chu I want to know the reasoning behind the convention

Comment: It's just a convention - no deeper implication. Like the universally accepted convention that clockwise is off for flow control valves and water taps.